# SwiftUI - how to increase Toggle's target touch size?

Tags: swift, swiftui, toggle, usability

I want to increase Toggle's target size for usability purposes.
It's easy with buttons using .frame(width: 200, height: 200) . But I don't know how to apply the same for toggles.

Here is my code. I have marked where it works and where it doesn't.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var test = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                print("button pressed")
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    // This works for Button
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            
            Toggle(isOn: Binding<Bool>(
                    get: { test },
                    set: {
                        test = $0
                    })) {
                Text("Done")
            }
            // This doesn't work for Toggle
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .labelsHidden()
        }
        
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
        Toggle(isOn: Binding<Bool>(
                get: { test },
                set: {
                    test = $0
                })) {
            Text("Done")
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .labelsHidden()
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                   test.toggle()
                }
        }
```

Comment: Oh! It works. But I needed to add `.contentShape(Rectangle())` before .onTapGesture :)